# Are continuous functions on measurable sets always measurable functions?

Tags: measure-theory

I was working through an exercise today when I realized that it would be useful to say of a measurable subset $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ that every function that is continuous on $E$ is measurable on $E$.

This seems to be true, as presumably a function $f: E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on $E$ iff for every open set $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, we have $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in the subspace topology of $E$, that is to say $f^{-1}(U)$ is an intersection of $E$ and some open set in $\mathbb{R}$, which presumably should have that it is measurable (which should have $f$ is measurable as it is measurable iff preimages of open sets are measurable). My question is whether or not this is a valid argument. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Yes, if $E$ is given the Borel $\sigma-$ algebra of it subspace topology, then any continuous real function on it is Borel measurable.